# How to convert a string to hash in perl without using regex or split

Tags: json, regex, perl

I have a function i cannot control which returns a string which is acutally a hash. It looks something like below:

```
{"offset":0,"limit":500,"count":0,"virtual_machines":[]}
```

I need to check if the count is greater than 0. Because the output is a string and not a hash, i am trying to split the string and get the output from it.

The snippet for the same is below:

```
my $output = '{"offset":0,"limit":500,"count":0,"virtual_machines":[]}';
$output =~ s/ +/ /g;
my @words = split /[:,"\s\/]+/, $output;
print Dumper(@words);
```

The output for this is:

```
$VAR1 = '{';
$VAR2 = 'offset';
$VAR3 = '0';
$VAR4 = 'limit';
$VAR5 = '500';
$VAR6 = 'count';
$VAR7 = '0';
$VAR8 = 'virtual_machines';
$VAR9 = '[]}';
```

Now, i can get the value $VAR7 and get the count.

Is there a way to convert a string to hash and then use the keys to get the values instead of using regex and split. Can someone help me out here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That string is in JSON format. I'd simply do

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);

my $output = '{"offset":0,"limit":500,"count":0,"virtual_machines":[]}';
my $data = decode_json $output;

print $data->{count}, "\n";
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting - parsing at as JSON means you don't get caught out by the nested data structures that JSON supports. Regex is an entirely inappropriate tool for this job. E.g. `virtual_machines` is a list, and if you're parsing badly, a machine called `"limit"` (or with a "limit" property) might cause real problems.

Answer (score -3):

If all colons are just separators, then you can replace them with '=>'s and eval the string.
That's probably unrealistic, though. So you can use JSON ... looks like the string is in JSON format. Try the following (worked for me :-):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';

# the string is JSON
my $jstr = '{"offset":0,"limit":500,"count":0,"virtual_machines":[]}';

# oversimplified (not using json ... o.k. if no colons anywhere but as separators
my $sstr = $jstr;
$sstr =~ s/:/=>/g;
my $href = eval "$sstr";
printf("From oversimplified eval, limit == %d\n", $href->{limit});

# using JSON (looks like string is in JSON format).
# get JSON::Parse from CPAN (sudo cpan JSON::Parse)
my $jref = parse_json($jstr);
printf("From JSON::Parse, limit == %d\n", $jref->{limit});

1;
```

Output:
From oversimplified eval, limit == 500
From JSON::Parse, limit == 500

Comment: Don't do `sudo cpan`. Why get `JSON::Parse` from CPAN if `JSON::PP` is a core module? Why recommend `JSON::Parse` at all? Its Unicode handling is broken by design. Why are you not using `warnings` and `strict`?

Comment: @melpomene, my example works. Did you downgrade me from 0 to -3 for a working example? If you know of an improvement, fine. But if you think JSON::Parse is "broken by design", then say so in the CPAN documentation for JSON::Parse. I don't see any issue there, open or closed, with your name. I don't believe your handling of my comment is in the intended spirit of stackoverflow.

Comment: I did not downvote you to -3. I only have one vote, like everyone else. In my comment I brought up four separate issues. You've addressed none of them (by either changing your code or telling me why I'm mistaken). As for the JSON::Parse documentation, see [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Parse#UTF-8-only): "*JSON::Parse only parses the UTF-8 format [...] `my $input_utf8 = decode ('UTF-16', $input); my $perl = parse_json ($input_utf8);`*", which shows a fundamental misunderstanding of encodings. It's unclear if `parse_json` takes UTF-8 (i.e. bytes in an encoding) or a decoded text string.

Comment: JSON::PP seems like a preferable approach. But it seemed to me that the essential point is that the output shown looks like JSON, and that there are existing Perl packages to handle that. Dumper still leaves you with parsing to do. The question does not go into UTF-XXX, although it could certainly be relevant in production. If it were actually claimed that the output is JSON, then we might want some error detection logic as well. I guess the other downvotes did not comment? BTW, I think we added our answers at almost the same time, since I didn't see yours when I started, but did when I saved.